# Image shrink in Expression blend

Tags: image

I am designing a picture in Expression Blend. I need some help with the sizing of the images. If I don't specify any size, it will render the image at full size, but I want it to be restricted by height and width. If the window resizes, the images should resize.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [Stretch property to Uniform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the height and width of the picture to 100%